# Mixing audio and video with ffmpeg

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am having an mp4 video (without audio), to which I want to add music using ffmpeg, and also want the output video to be of the same length as the input video.

But, as a result, I am getting an video merged with audio, but consuming a little more time (abt 1-2 seconds) in the start with a black screen.

I am using the following command for my desired output.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i video.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.avi
```

Please suggest, what modifications should I do to get my desired output.

Comment: Usage questions about the FFmpeg command line interface belong on [SU]. Don't forget to include the full, uncut command line output when posting. I think you should simply use the `-shortest` option and try your command again.

Comment: @slhck: I even used -shortest option but that too didn't work for me.

Comment: hi narendra,how to merge audio with video in android?if you know plz share with me.

Comment: @rams: I mentioned the command for merging audio with video, in my original post. Please use that for merging.

Comment: i already used one command line but that was worked in emulator.not worked in real devices. rooted phones only working on  that commandline.

Comment: @Narendra - can you please help me with post?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157030/how-to-include-ffmpeg-functions-in-android-code/14157200#14157200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-itsoffset is the option you are looking for. It will do the offseting for you.

Comment: Then please suggest how to use it.