# How to include FFMPEG functions in android code

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

My aim is to build a video file by combining an audio clip and an image for android.

Using cygwin, I was able to create the video by combining an image and an audio clip as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i allmapeople.mp3 -i Penguins.jpg video_finale.mpg
```

But I want this to happen in the mobile device within my eclipse project.

Please tell me how this should be done.....

Comment: can someone tell me why my post was down voted? Did I ask anything wrong here??